# Programmatically generated table not matching parent width

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, tablerow, android-tablelayout

I am trying to dynamically generate my activity layout but for some reason I can't get my TableLayout or my TableRow to match the parent width. I am using a relative layout, then I create my TableLayout and fill it with rows before adding my TableLayout to my RelativeLayout.

Here is my onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    context = this;

    RelativeLayout mainLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );
    mainLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeLayout);

    //Create the signature views
    //createPage(mainLayout);

    setupPage(mainLayout);

    setContentView(mainLayout);
}
```

Here is my `setupPage()` code:

```
private void setupPage(RelativeLayout mainLayout)
{
    TableLayout mainTable = new TableLayout(context);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tableLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    mainLayout.setLayoutParams(tableLayoutParams);
    mainTable.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle);

    //JOB DESCRIPTION title
    mainTable.addView(getRowTitle("JOB DESCRIPTION"));

    //----   END   ----
    mainLayout.addView(mainTable);
}

private TableRow getRowTitle(String text)
{
    TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
    TableLayout.LayoutParams rowLayout = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );
    row.setLayoutParams(rowLayout);
    row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle);//so i can see the outline of the row

    /*TextView title = new TextView(context);
    TableRow.LayoutParams editLayout = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    editLayout.setMargins(15,0,0,0);
    title.setLayoutParams(editLayout);
    title.setText(text);

    row.addView(title);*/

    return row;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you set as the `LayoutParams` for the parent `RelativeLayout` the `tableLayoutParams`(which is of type `TableLayout.LayoutParams`)?

Comment: I thought the child has to have the layout params of the parent? I've tried to use TableLayout.LayoutParams but that didn't chagne anything

Comment: A small error in the comment above, instead of setting the `LayoutParams` on the `mainLayout`(`mainLayout.setLayoutParams(tableLayoutParams);` in the `setupPage()` method) set it on the actual `TableLayout`: `mainTable.setLayoutParams(tableLayoutParams);`

Comment: Aha. that was the problem. I accidentally had `mainLayout.setLayoutParams` instead of `mainTable.setLayoutParams`......... can you post it as an answer so I can accept it? Thank you for finding my stupidity lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not setting the `LayoutParams` on the proper view(which most likely ends up with the default `LayoutParams`). In the `setupPage()` method you do:

```
mainLayout.setLayoutParams(tableLayoutParams);
```

instead of setting it on the `TableLayout`:

```
mainTable.setLayoutParams(tableLayoutParams);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
private void setupPage(RelativeLayout mainLayout)
{
TableLayout mainTable = new TableLayout(context);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tableLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
mainTable.setLayoutParams(tableLayoutParams);
mainTable.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle);

//JOB DESCRIPTION title
mainTable.addView(getRowTitle("JOB DESCRIPTION"));

//----   END   ----
mainLayout.addView(mainTable);
}
```